# Segmentation fault in element_t array

Tags: c++, arrays, cryptography

I use the [PBC](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) library for a project, and I try to have a `element_t` array, where to store some data.

I get a `segmentation fault` error when debugging with `gdb` when I try to copy an `element_t` into the array.

Here is a MWE :

```
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <pbc.h>
#include <pbc_test.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const int t = 2;
    const int n = 3;
    element_t r[t];
    element_t s[n];
    pairing_t pairing;
    element_t P, s0, P0;

    pbc_demo_pairing_init(pairing, argc, argv); 

    cout<<"SETUP STAGE"<<endl;

    element_init_G1(P, pairing);
    element_random(P);
    element_printf("P = \t%B\n", P);

    /* Build the table with each element is r_i */
    element_t r_i;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {   
        element_init_Zr(r_i, pairing);
        element_random(r_i);
        /* Put r_i into the array */
        element_set(r[i], r_i); // <--- segmentation fault here
        element_clear(r_i);

    }
    /* Set s = r0 */
    element_init_Zr(s0, pairing);
    element_random(s0);
    /* Put it in the first place in the vector of all si */
    element_set(s[0], r[0]);

    /* Compute P = s*P0 */
    element_mul_zn(P0, P, s0);
    element_printf("P0 = %B\n", P0);

    element_clear(P);

    pairing_clear(pairing);

    return 0;
}
```

I got this as error :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000002721f in ?? ()
```

As anyone already tried putting `element_t`s in arrays ?

Comment: I don't know about this library but where is "n" defined?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this line when copying. It's an integer, same as t.

Comment: I'm going to guess that `element_t` needs to be initialized. If that was the case initializing with `element_t r[t] = {}` should solve your problem.

Comment: May be you have to initialize the elements of the array. Try to put this line before the SEGFAULT line: `element_init_Zr(r[i], pairing);`

Comment: Yep, it solved my problem. You write the answer, or I do it ?

Comment: I was just guessing so I think you should write the answer

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the error came from not initialisasing of the `element_t`

Here is the MWE corrected, which works :

```
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <pbc.h>
#include <pbc_test.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const int t = 2;
    const int n = 3;
    element_t r[t];
    element_t s[n];
    pairing_t pairing;
    element_t P, s0, P0;
        element_init_G1(P, pairing);
        element_init_Zr(s0, pairing);
        element_init_G1(P0, pairing);


    pbc_demo_pairing_init(pairing, argc, argv); 

    cout<<"SETUP STAGE"<<endl;

    element_random(P);
    element_printf("P = \t%B\n", P);

    /* Build the table with each element is r_i */
    element_t r_i;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {   
        element_init_Zr(r[i], pairing); // Resolved the problem
        element_init_Zr(r_i, pairing);

        element_random(r_i);
        /* Put r_i into the array */
        element_set(r[i], r_i);
        element_clear(r_i);

    }
    /* Set s = r0 */
    element_random(s0);

    /* Put it in the first place in the vector of all si */
   element_init_Zr(s[0], pairing);
    element_set(s[0], r[0]);

    /* Compute P = s*P0 */
    element_mul_zn(P0, P, s0);
    element_printf("P0 = %B\n", P0);

    element_clear(P);

    pairing_clear(pairing);

    return 0;
}
```